# Why don't some demomen suffer from afterburn?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro, tf2-demoman

I've noticed lately (maybe the last couple of months), playing as Pyro, that sometimes I'll light a demoman on fire and he doesn't suffer any afterburn. As soon as I stop hitting him with flames, they go out. Is there some new Demoman item or something that is causing this?  I'm quite sure they are not being extinguished by a teammate or by picking up a health pack.

Comment: The [July 10, 2013 update](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/July_10,_2013_Patch) included a number of changes to increase the usefulness of underused weapons. I recommend taking a look at it to see what other changes were made (though some of them have since been nerfed).

Comment: @AustinMohr They could use another one of those, now that the Wee Booties are rendered completely useless by the Tide Turner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Chargin' Targe adds an immunity to afterburn effect. You can still light them on fire, but they will be extinguished as if they were a pyro. This was changed in the patch on July 10, 2013:

> Changed attributes: Added Afterburn immunity.

[Source](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Chargin%27_Targe#Update_history)

Comment: Do you know if it's always been that way, or if it was changed in a recent update? I never noticed it before.

Comment: @DanC It was changed pretty recently. Let me look up exactly when.